# Are the service names, provided in the serviceconfigs response, consistent across all IBM Connections 4.5 installations?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

Reference to documentation: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/dx/Accessing_other_applications_from_one_application_ic45

The REST API call to `https://{server}/{service}/serviceconfigs` returns an ATOM XML `<feed>` that contains an `<entry>` for each service.

Example from Greenhouse:

```
<entry>
  <category term="service-config" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type"></category>
  <title type="text">files</title>
  <id>urn:lsid:ibm.com:config:files:com.ibm.lc.48f111ae-5cff-41e5-b938-0c2e5941061e</id>
  <link href="http://greenhouse.lotus.com/files" rel="alternate" type="text/html"></link>
  <link href="https://greenhouse.lotus.com/files" rel="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/alternate-ssl" type="text/html"></link>
  <updated>2014-02-04T17:30:14.963Z</updated>
</entry>
```

To ask my question a few different ways:

Is it correct to assume that the `<title>` of the entry is a consistent identifier?
Can we use that value, across any Connections installation, to locate a particular service's URL for that site? 
Will the Files service, for example, always be named `files` in any site's service configs feed?

I have commented on the documentation's wiki page with the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  it's part of the ATOM XML standard that is emitted from IBM Connections. 
you can always validate it by hitting the service.do  https://greenhouse.lotus.com/files/atom/service

it's also part of the documented API

should add, that you can use the ${SERVICE_CONFIG} variables in your iWidgets.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. The above URL didn't work for me. But this one did: https://greenhouse.lotus.com/files/basic/api/introspection